# ITextSharp HTML to PDF Conversion CSS Images are not showing after convesion

Tags: c#, css, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to convert an HTML with CSS in to Pdf and it has been successful. But once I tried to add an image to a div from a CSS the Converted Pdf  won't show the image

This is my code

**For Pdf Content Type**

using System;
                using System.IO;
                using System.Web.Mvc;

```
            namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
            {
                public class PdfContent : ActionResult
                {
                    public MemoryStream MemoryStream { get; set; }
                    public string FileName { get; set; }

                    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
                    {
                        if (context == null)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
                        }

                        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                        response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
                        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName + ".pdf");
                        response.OutputStream.Write(MemoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, MemoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**The Action which Invoke the Pdf**

```
  public ActionResult GeneratePdf()
                        {
                            var cssText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\sansa\Desktop\Ground Operations\HTMLResources\grace.css");
                            var htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\sansa\Desktop\Ground Operations\HTMLResources\grace.html");

                            var cssArray = cssText.Trim().Split('}');

                            var cssClassesString = string.Join("} ", cssArray);

                            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                            var document = new Document();
                            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                            document.Open();

                            using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssClassesString)))
                            {
                                using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlText)))
                                {
                                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                                }
                            }

                            document.Close();

                            var pdfContent = new PdfContent
                            {
                                MemoryStream = memoryStream,
                                FileName = "SomeName"
                            };
                            return pdfContent;
                        }
```

**The CSS  classes**

```
                .main_div{background-color:#F8F8F8; vertical-align:center; z-index:1000000; border-width:1px; border-style:solid ;border-radius: 2px;border-color: #E0E0E0; width:400px; height:200px}
                .text_one{color: #003300;}
                .text_two{color: #0000ca;}
                .text_three{color: #e40000;}
                .tbl_page{
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    color: black;
                    background-color: cornsilk;
                    display: block;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-color: wheat;
                    border-width: 1px;;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    white-space: normal;
                    line-height: normal;
                }

                .tbl_cell{
                    background-color: honeydew;
                }

                td, th {
                    display: table-cell;
                }

                .tbr_raw{
                    background-color: #66CCFF;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .image_div_background{
                    background-image: url('violin-clip-art-violin-clip-art-1.jpg');
                    height: 400px; width: 400px;
                }
```

This code will generate a clean HTML to Pdf Conversion 
Except it won't show the image which applied for the div's background in the converted file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also tried to assign image to div via CSS but not working so when I am tried to add img tag with scr attribute inside div tag then it will work for me

**try this**

```
<div class="image_div_background">
<img scr="www.yourDomineName.com/violin-clip-art-violin-clip-art-1.jpg"/>
<div>
```

hope fully it will work for you

Comment: I cannot use inline styles

Comment: I am not saying you applied Inline css you just add your background image  via img element rest of css write your css file

Comment: can u provide html or aspx page?

Comment: <img src="violin-clip-art-violin-clip-art-1.jpg" />
                         Replace with
<img scr="www.yourDomineName.com/violin-clip-art-violin-clip-art-1.jpg"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85194/discussion-between-sansa-kirov-and-vakeel).